# How costly are small network calls compared to a single big one?

Tags: ios, networking, backend, assets, gpx

Original question was: *Is it best to store GPX routes in back-end as multiple individual files or as a single monolith one?*

Hello, I'm currently building my back-end CMS with Squidex for my iOS app and I'm wondering what would be the best way to store a particular category of files.

I'm building a hiking app that will contain multiple natural parks. Natural parks are the topmost element of my object hierarchy. They contain many fields and we don't create one everyday as they represent a lot of work.
All these parks contain hikes. The hikes' routes should be displayed by the app using GPX file format.

People using the app will typically only browse through a few parks and in these few parks, will check something like 3 or 4 hikes. Parks will contain from 10 to 200 hikes depending on their sizes, and every hike will have its GPX route.

I'm wondering what the best approach would be. **Should I set up a GPX file field for every hike, or should I make only one GPX file for the whole natural park?** That "monolith" GPX file would contain all the hikes' routes identified by an ID.

The main considerations I have are:

- Networking costs *in time and energy consumed* by the device: people will use this app in places where network might be scarce so I have to manage it carefully. What would be the most expensive between a single GET call for a monolith file, or let's say 5 to 10 GET calls for multiple small files in an extended period of time?
- Networking costs in *data*: getting the whole file will surely be more expensive in terms of data transferred and impact on the user's cellular plan. But we're talking about at most 10Mb I think. GPX files are not that big and even the monolith shouldn't be bigger than a few images.
- Hosting costs: most CMSs charge by network calls and not necessarily by how much data is transferred. However for assets specifically, it's often the opposite.

Given these considerations, I realize that a rephrasing of my question could be: **how costly are small network calls compared to a single big one?**.

Of course, we're talking about a back-end that serves mobile customers so keep in mind that the network calls will be performed in poor networking conditions inducing longer download speeds and more energy drawn out by the phone's radios.

You may notice that I'm really tempted by the monolithic approach, but given my small experience in back-end development I'm afraid of missing something.

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: It depends on how much data you are willing to lose at one time. Packets will be lost, and the more data in a packet, the more data is lost when a packet is lost.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a few days thinking and reading about the topic, for my particular situation I'm going to do multiple individual requests to get the GPX files.

The rationale is that though multiple requests could be an issue in poor networking conditions, having a huge request for a file weighing more than 10MB will probably cause long loading times when opening a park. Also, it leaves room for having a premium option to download all hikes at once and improves efficiency: the user won't download data they don't need.